# Drupal 8, just after installing, css files can't loaded, server error 500

Tags: installation, drupal-8, requirements

I have just installed Drupal 8.5.4, like this:

- get the code from the site
- extracted it in the s folder on my site ('katelec.com/s').
- create database, installed the site.

when trying to access the site, no styles loaded.

when trying to access any css file i get server error 500.

the style are generated correctly and lay in the corresponding folder.

everything went well when I disabled css / js aggregation.

PHP Version 7.0.30
Memory limit: 500M
TRUSTED HOST SETTINGS

Why I get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing server log.

Drupal's .htaccess files has a command to stop cgi from running.

And it seems that the shared hosting I'm using disabled cgi.

> So I edited .htaccess file by removing that cgi command.